# How do I query CloudSearch for a document that contains more than one value in a list or array?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

example documents:

```
{
    "name":"Bob Belcher",
    "children":[
        "Tina",
        "Louise",
        "Gene"
    ]
}
```

I want to find a document by asking:
contains children "Tina" AND contains children "Louise"

Similarly how can I do:
contains children "Tina" AND NOT contains children "Jack"

Can this be done with child objects instead of strings?
contains children with name="Tina" AND contains children with name="Louise"

example documents:

```
{
    "name":"Bob Belcher",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Tina"
        },
        {
            "name":"Louise"
        },
        {
            "name":"Gene"
        }
    ]
}
```

One more, can we do this many layers deep?

```
{
    "name":"Bob Belcher",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Tina",
            "pets":[
                "Spot",
                "Snowball"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"Louise",
            "pets":[
                "Liz"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"Gene"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I ask something like:
Contains children that contains pets "Spot" AND Contains children that contains pets "Snowball"

Answer (score 0):

1) The attribute `children` defined as `SET` Dynamodb data type, it is possible to filter with `CONTAINS` and `NOT CONTAINS`. Example:-

```
FilterExpression: "  contains (product, :productSet) AND not contains (product, :productSetNotContains)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':key1' : 2016,
        ':titleval' :  "The Big New Movie 1",
        ':productSet' : "milk",
        ':productSetNotContains' : "egg"

    }
```

2) The attribute `children` defined as `LIST` DynamoDB data type, it is possible to filter using `CONTAINS`.

```
var childrenTina = {"name":"Tina"};
var childrenLouise = {"name":"Louise"};

FilterExpression: "  contains (children, :childrenTina) AND contains (children, :childrenLouise)   ",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':key1' : 2016,
        ':titleval' :  "The Big New Movie 1",
        ':childrenTina' : childrenTina,
        ':childrenLouise' : childrenLouise

    }
```

3) For deeply layered array, filter can be done using CONTAINS if the entire value of an element is known i.e. in order to match Tina, the value of Pets attributes are also required.

In DynamoDB terms, the below structure means there is a `MAP inside LIST` i.e. each element in the LIST is a MAP. As long as the entire MAP data is available, the CONTAINS function can be used to filter the data.

```
"name":"Tina",
            "pets":[
                "Spot",
                "Snowball"
            ]
```